# Setting fixed address/network for docker0 bridge interface on Ubuntu

Tags: docker

I am running docker 1.7 on ubuntu 15.04 and I would basically like to assign a fixed configuration to the docker0 interface. I was expecting

```
docker -d --bip=172.17.42.1/16
```

to do the trick, but it does not. Instead it fails:

```
FATA[0000] Error starting daemon: Error initializing network controller: Error creating default "bridge" network: bridge IPv4 (10.1.42.1) does not match requested configuration 172.17.42.1
```

I understand it can be done setting up the interface before launching he daemon using `-b`, but that seems overly complicated. Besides if that's what you should do, what would be the purpose of `--bip`?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out by now. The command from my question works as expected when `docker0` is not configured or already has that IP address. The thing is that docker does not **change** addresses of existing interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure I understand, but maybe you want to configure the DNS server for use by docker??? In the **/etc/default/docker** file add the following:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 172.17.42.1"
```

And restart docker afterwards.